# Capture events happening inside a directory

Tags: java, watchservice

Im watching a directory using `Java 7 nio WatchService` by using below method.

```
Path myDir = Paths.get("/rootDir");

try {
  WatchService watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
  myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, 
  StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

  WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

  List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
  for (WatchEvent event : events) {
    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
      System.out.println("Created: " + event.context().toString());
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Created: " + event.context().toString());
    }
    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
      System.out.println("Delete: " + event.context().toString());
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Delete: " + event.context().toString());
    }
    if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
      System.out.println("Modify: " + event.context().toString());
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Modify: " + event.context().toString());
    }
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

But the above method only respond in one events happen in the directory after that watcher does not respond to the events happen in that folder. Is there a way that I can modify this to capture all events happen inside the folder. I also want to modify this to capture events happen in sub folders too. Can someone help me with that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Apache Commons IO File Monitoring
it will also capture events happening in sub folders too

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationListener;
import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationListenerAdaptor;
import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationMonitor;
import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver;

public class Monitor {

    public Monitor() {

    }

    //path to a folder you are monitoring .

    public static final String FOLDER = MYPATH;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("monitoring started");
        // The monitor will perform polling on the folder every 5 seconds
        final long pollingInterval = 5 * 1000;

        File folder = new File(FOLDER);

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            // Test to see if monitored folder exists
            throw new RuntimeException("Directory not found: " + FOLDER);
        }

        FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(folder);
        FileAlterationMonitor monitor =
                new FileAlterationMonitor(pollingInterval);
        FileAlterationListener listener = new FileAlterationListenerAdaptor() {
            // Is triggered when a file is created in the monitored folder
            @Override
            public void onFileCreate(File file) {

                    // "file" is the reference to the newly created file
                    System.out.println("File created: "+ file.getCanonicalPath());


            }

            // Is triggered when a file is deleted from the monitored folder
            @Override
            public void onFileDelete(File file) {
                try {
                    // "file" is the reference to the removed file
                    System.out.println("File removed: "+ file.getCanonicalPath());
                    // "file" does not exists anymore in the location
                    System.out.println("File still exists in location: "+ file.exists());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        };

        observer.addListener(listener);
        monitor.addObserver(observer);
        monitor.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this capture an event like changing content inside a text file.?

Comment: no it will just check if any new file is created or deleted in a given directory

Comment: it will also check if any new file is created or deleted inside the subfolders

Answer (score 5):

From [the JavaDoc of `WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html):

> A Watchable object is registered with a watch service by invoking its register method, returning a WatchKey to represent the registration. When an event for an object is detected the key is signalled, and if not currently signalled, it is queued to the watch service so that it can be retrieved by consumers that invoke the poll or take methods to retrieve keys and process events. Once the events have been processed the consumer invokes the key's reset method to reset the key which allows the key to be signalled and re-queued with further events.

You are only calling [`watcher.take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#take%28%29) once.

To watch for further events, you must call [`watchKey.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#reset%28%29) after consuming the `WatchEvent`s. Put all this in a loop.

```
while (true) {
  WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();
  List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
  for (WatchEvent event : events) {
    // process event
  }
  watchKey.reset();
}
```

Also take a look at [the relevant section of the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).