# Apache Commons IO File Monitoring capture events in subfolders

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm using the following code to capture events in a given folder. It works fine, but my question is how can I capture events in sub folders in my given folder as well?

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationListener;
  import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationListenerAdaptor;
  import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationMonitor;
  import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationObserver;

  public class Monitor {

public Monitor() {

}

//path to a folder you are monitoring .

public static final String FOLDER = MYPATH;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("monitoring started");
    // The monitor will perform polling on the folder every 5 seconds
    final long pollingInterval = 5 * 1000;

    File folder = new File(FOLDER);

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        // Test to see if monitored folder exists
        throw new RuntimeException("Directory not found: " + FOLDER);
    }

    FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(folder);
    FileAlterationMonitor monitor =
            new FileAlterationMonitor(pollingInterval);
    FileAlterationListener listener = new FileAlterationListenerAdaptor() {
        // Is triggered when a file is created in the monitored folder
        @Override
        public void onFileCreate(File file) {

                // "file" is the reference to the newly created file
                System.out.println("File created: "+ file.getCanonicalPath());


        }

        // Is triggered when a file is deleted from the monitored folder
        @Override
        public void onFileDelete(File file) {
            try {
                // "file" is the reference to the removed file
                System.out.println("File removed: "+ file.getCanonicalPath());
                // "file" does not exists anymore in the location
                System.out.println("File still exists in location: "+ file.exists());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
    };

    observer.addListener(listener);
    monitor.addObserver(observer);
    monitor.start();
}
}
```

I've read here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678170/capture-events-happening-inside-a-directory) that this code is suppose to capture events in sub folders as well, but I does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you make regarding the hyperlink after your code is not accurate. The code in [Capture events happening inside a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678170/capture-events-happening-inside-a-directory) DOES capture certain events (file create, file delete) in the main/root directory and subfolders. It does not monitor file **modification** or **folder operations** (create, delete, rename, etc.).

I have just tested it on 3 levels down (nested subfolders). As such the code you are referring to accomplishes what you are asking for. If you need something different please re-phrase/re-word your question.

If you need more information on the subject you might find this link: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationListenerAdaptor.html useful. It definitely helped me.