# Load 1GB of file to Kafka producer directly from my local machine

Tags: apache-kafka

I have experimented with the basic examples of publishing random messages from producer to consumer by command line.
Now i want to publish all the 1GB of data present in my local machine. For that i am struggling to load that 1GB of data to producer.

Help me out please.

Comment: what's the problem though?

Comment: reading many files(that folder makes 1GB) which from a location in kafka.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply dump a file by simple redirection to kafka topic. Assuming 1.xml is 1GB file then you can use following command.

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test123 < ./1.xml
```

1. But please make sure that you set following properties in producer xml.
   `socket.request.max.bytes`, `socket.receive.buffer.bytes`, `socket.send.buffer.bytes`.
2. You need to set `max.message.bytes` for test123 topic if your message size is big.
3. Also change Xmx parameter in `console-producer.sh` to avoid Out of Memory issue.

These are the general steps to load data in kafka.
We will able to understand more if you provide the error.

So couple of approaches can help: 
1) You can use big data platforms like Flume which are built for such use cases. 
2) If you want to implement you own code then you can use Apache commons Lib which will help you in capturing events when a new file arrives in folder ([Capture events happening inside a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678170/capture-events-happening-inside-a-directory)) and once you have that then you can call the code which publishes the data on kafka. 
3) In our project we use Logstash API to do the same which fetches from a folder and publishes data from file to kafka and then processes it through Storm.

Comment: Your command is to push data from producer to broker. This i already know. My make producer read big big file from a location in real time.All new files at a location should be read by producer and sent to broker automatically.

Comment: I am not facing any error. I am trouble in starting only. I mean how to make producer read all files in real time manner from a location

Comment: So couple of approaches can help: 1) You can use big data platforms like Flume which are built for such use cases. 2) If you want to implement you own code then you can use Apache commons Lib  which will help you in capturing events when a new file arrives in folder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678170/capture-events-happening-inside-a-directory) and once you have that then you can call the code which publishes the data on kafka. 3) In our project we use Logstash API to do the same which fetches from a folder and publishes data from file to kafka and then processes it through Storm.